# CDK deploy of multiple stacks, without wildcard or --all

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm attempting to simplify an issue from work which has seen me and multiple others pull our hair. I/we need to be able to deploy a stack via CDK which in turn creates multiple stacks within, across multiple regions for these 'child' stacks.

Take the following example, the main stack, which creates a (global) role, and then a few extra stacks, each across mutliple regions:

```js
export class MultiStackRootStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    const someRole = new iam.Role(
      this,
      "Lambda_role",
      {
        assumedBy : new iam.CompositePrincipal(
          new iam.ServicePrincipal("edgelambda.amazonaws.com"),
          new iam.ServicePrincipal("lambda.amazonaws.com"),
        ),
      }
    )

    let regions: string[] =  [
      "us-east-1",
      "us-east-2",
      "us-west-1",
      "us-west-2"
    ];
    
    regions.forEach(region => {
      new MultiStackStorageStack(this, `StorageStack-${region}`, {
         env: {
          region: region,
          account: "<account #>"
         }
        }
      );

      new MultiStackQueueStack(this, `QueueStack-${region}`, {
        env: {
         region: region,
         account: "<account #>"
        }
       }
     );
    });
```

The other/children stacks are defined as:

```js
export class MultiStackStorageStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    console.log(`Storage Stack ${props?.env?.region}`)

    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(scope, `Bucket-${props?.env?.region}`, {
      blockPublicAccess: s3.BlockPublicAccess.BLOCK_ALL,
      encryption: s3.BucketEncryption.S3_MANAGED,
      enforceSSL: true,
      versioned: true,
      removalPolicy: RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
      bucketName: `myuniquetestbucket-${props?.env?.region}`
    });
    
  }
}
```

and

```js
export class MultiStackQueueStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    console.log(`Queue Stack ${props?.env?.region}`)

    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, `TheQueue-${props?.env?.region}`, {
      queueName: `TheQueue-${props?.env?.region}`,
    });
    
  }
}
```

When it comes to do a CDK synth or deploy, multiple stacks are generated, not unexpectedly, and if I do a deploy of just "MultiStackRootStack", the role shows up, along with the buckets (all in the same region I'm starting within), but no traces of the other stacks in Cloud Formation, nor the Queues. If I throw a wildcard in, say "MultiStackRootStack*", same results. Only when I get to "MultiStackRootStack/*" will the child stacks be deployed, but not the parent.

One partial work around, is to have both the Queue & Storage stacks inherit from NestedStack, then a cdk deploy of MultiStackRootStack will deploy all of the things... but only to the single region I'm triggering this from. As I understand things, NestedStacks are only normally supported in the same region as the parent stack, and given I'm doing multiple regions (though only partially successfully), that doesn't work for me.

Can anyone suggest what I'm missing here? Why won't a deploy of my one stack, which very clearly creates other stacks also deploy them without a wild card or a --all?

I've seen countless examples of deployments of multiple stacks within stacks, or across regions, yet for some reason the way I'm trying to do it doesn't, and I'm going bald trying to sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cloudformation, a stack cannot create other stacks. In CDK, you can create stacks *in the scope of other stacks*, but each stack will be deployed independently in the end. You can use `"MultiStackRootStack*"` to deploy all of them, this should include the parent stack as well.

There is a bug in your code, though - your bucket is created in the parent stack because you are passing the parent scope.

Replace `new s3.Bucket(scope, ...` with `new s3.Bucket(this, ...`. This is why you saw the buckets being created alongside the role.